# proper way to push view controller on didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am working with an application in which there is a table view controller. When the user clicks on the cell, I want to display specifics for that cell in a separate view controller. My first attempt at doing this was the following:

```
CellViewController * cvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"cellVC"];
[cvc.name setText:fName];
[cvc.homeNum setText:hNum];
[cvc.mobileNum setText:mNum];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:cvc animated:NO];
```

However, this produces a view controller without the updated values fName, hNum, and mNum. I guess I have 2 questions:
1) Is there a strong difference in terms of good practice for instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier vs. PerformSegueWithIdentifier. (I'm using the former currently because I just don't like segues as much)
2) If instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier is an okay way of doing it, why are those values not being updated? Instead the raw 'Label' just shows up

Note: I have looked at [performSegueWithIdentifier vs instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8926606/performseguewithidentifier-vs-instantiateviewcontrollerwithidentifier) And I believe the question is slightly different/they didn't really answer my question. They also seem to claim the former way is bad practice but I have seen other cases where people used that way, so I am confused.

Thanks

Comment: You will love segues when you will need different ways for presenting view controllers. For example push master view controller on iPhone and push master view controller and presenting details in split view controller on iPad.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that contols, like `cvc.name` is not initialized, because after instantiating view controller is not loaded.

Declare properties in CellViewController, like:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * nameString;
```

and in CellViewController.m

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
[name setText:_nameString];
}
```