# Difference between StoryboardID and StoryboardSegueIdentifier

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, segue

We can move from our `mainViewController` to our `detailViewController` using segueIdentifiers. Example:

```
performSegueWithIdentifier("toDetailViewController", sender: self)
```

We can also manually create our `detailViewController` from our storyboard using a StoryboardID which then gets pushed or presented from `mainViewController`. Example:

```
let detailViewController: UIViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("detailViewController") as UIViewController
self.present(detailViewController)
```

My question is: what is the difference between these approaches? They seem to do the exact same thing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [performSegueWithIdentifier vs instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8926606/performseguewithidentifier-vs-instantiateviewcontrollerwithidentifier)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They both storyboard reference related identifiers. The main difference is one `performSegueWithIdentifier` instantiates an object based on a segue's and `where the segue points to` while the other `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` instantiates a unique Viewcontroller based on the Viewcontroller identifier (not the segue).

You can have multiple segues with the same identifier in different places in the storyboard, while Viewcontroller in a storyboard cannot have the same identifier.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that one is done through storyboards (you can see the segue arrow), the other one is done programmatically. It's the same as if you asked what is a difference between programming UI in swift and programming it using storyboards.

In first case you don't even have to call `performSegueWithIdentifier`, you can bind the segue to a button in storyboards, thus using only storyboards without any swift code.

While there are many articles talking for storyboards, I really recommend taking a look at [this one](http://inessential.com/2013/03/06/how_much_or_how_little_i_use_interface) that looks at it in a bit different light.